# SVN commit does nothing

Tags: svn, ubuntu-12.04

I installed a svn repo on Ubuntu 12.04, and need to use svn from both mac and windows clients. I followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion) to get svn running using  custom svn:// protocol, and I can check out my repo successfully.  The server does not ask for any authentication when checking out ???

on the mac client - command line - I commit, it is supposed to say

```
$ svn commit -m "edit 3 svn test"
Sending        a
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 3.
```

But this is what actually happens:

```
$ svn commit -m "added howto section."
```

Nothing. svn log does not indicate any update.

If I ask svn status, I get a complete list of all directories that I copied into the local working copy and need to be updated, but none of the files inside these directories:

```
$ svn status
?       app/Plugin/Metrics/Test
?       app/Plugin/Metrics/Model
?       app/Plugin/Metrics/Console
?       app/Plugin/Metrics/Controller
?       app/Plugin/Metrics/Config
?       app/Plugin/Metrics/Lib
?       app/Plugin/Metrics/View
```

The '?' indicates that all these listed directories are not in version control. However, no changed files are listed.  Just to make it clear - most of these directories listed above contain new files that I want to add or commit into the repo. These files are not listed, only the directories.

If I try to 'svn add' one of these directories, specifically, I get

```
$ svn add app/Plugin/Metrics/Model
svn: warning: 'app/Plugin/Metrics/Model' is already under version control
```

If I manually try to 'svn add' a file that I copied into one of these directories in the local working copy, I get

```
svn add app/Plugin/Metrics/Controller/MetricsMetricsController.php 
svn: warning: 'app/Plugin/Metrics/Controller/MetricsMetricsController.php' is already under version control
```

If I manually try to commit this same file, I get

```
 svn ci app/Plugin/Metrics/Controller/MetricsMetricsController.php
```

Nothing.  No feedback from svn on the client.  I am running svnserve on the ubuntu box in the foreground to see if it gives me any debugging info but it also shows nothing.

```
svnserve -d --foreground -r /galaxypool/svn
```

Reeeealy frustrating problem.  Any ideas how to get SVN to commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually did the following:
- moved my new directory tree from the local working copy to the desktop.
- issued:

```
svn delete app/Plugin/Metrics
D         app/Plugin/Metrics
```

And then commit - this deleted the corrupted Metrics folder from the repo:

```
svn commit -m "delete metrics"
Deleting       app/Plugin/Metrics

Committed revision 16.
```

Then I went to my directory tree and deleted all the hidden '.svn' folders, and copied the tree back into the local working set. svn status said

```
svn status
?       wezwa
?       app/Plugin/Metrics
```

Then I added the tree back again using svn add:

```
svn add app/Plugin/Metrics/
A         app/Plugin/Metrics
A         app/Plugin/Metrics/Config
A         app/Plugin/Metrics/Config/bootstrap.php
A         app/Plugin/Metrics/Config/cache.php ...etc
```

And commit:

```
svn commit -m "upload metrics"
Adding         app/Plugin/Metrics
Adding         app/Plugin/Metrics/Config
Adding         app/Plugin/Metrics/Config/Schema
...etc
```

Tested from the windows system and it worked.  The files are safe in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to add new files for Version control. For example:

```
svn add app/Plugin/Metrics/Test
```

After that, committing results in those files to be placed under version control.

BUT, before working on another client, you need to update the working copy there.

```
svn update
```

That will give you the actual status of the repository. You will have conflicts if the files already exist locally. You will have to solve those conflicts somehow.

**Edit**:
It seems as if you have a broken working copy due to manually moving around .svn directories. Try to do it all again; start with a clean fresh new working copy of your repository. Do an export (not checkout) of the directories you want to include into the new working copy and copy them over.

Remember that this is not the best thing to do; you can use externals to relate to another repository, or if you need to change something there use "vendor branches" (like described here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html)

Comment: I checked out the complete cackephp folder structure - the svn server did not ask for user authentication. Then I copied the complete metrics folder structure, including new files into the local working copy. In the question above, I did exactly what you asked - 'svn add app/Plugin/Metrics/Model
svn: warning: 'app/Plugin/Metrics/Model' is already under version control.' svn update says `At revision 15.`

Comment: did you copy around those ".svn" subfolders? If so, THAT is your problem. Delete all of them but those of your workingcopy.

Comment: I don't understand.  Must I delete all the .svn directories in the new directory tree that I copied to the working copy locally? I edited the question above to clear a few things up.

Comment: @FrancoisStark Yes, completely correct. Which svn-client version do you use? In Versions prior to 1.7, Subversion will place a .svn subfolder in every f**** folder it checks out, you will have to delete all of them before you copy a folder into another working copy. From 1.7 on, there is only one .svn folder, which makes life much easier.

Comment: ok. I deleted all the .svn directories in the new tree.  If I try to add the new tree, it says 'svn add app/Plugin/Metrics/
svn: warning: 'app/Plugin/Metrics' is already under version control'

Comment: if I try to check in the new tree, it says svn ci
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Directory 'app/Plugin/Metrics/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing

Comment: svn status now says `?       wezwa
~       app/Plugin/Metrics` and ~ means 'versioned item is obstructed by some item of a different kind' ???

Comment: svnserve version 1.6.17.  Installed into ubuntu last week.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24713/discussion-between-argeman-and-francois-stark)